# Maven is downloading jars of its dependency

Tags: maven

I have a pom file that has a single dependency. I want maven to download the dependency and wrap it in a new jar. However, when I run `mvn clean package`, it looks for the dependency, finds the dependency, and then looks at it's pom file and attempts to download all dependency of that dependency. How do I tell maven to not look at that dependencies' pom file and just download it?

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0

    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.eddie.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-wrapper</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eddie</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/22513588/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>eddie-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/32301501/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.nxtech.batch.Processor</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goals>install</goals>
                    <preparationGoals>install</preparationGoals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.eddie.myApp</groupId>
            <artifactId>myAwesomeReusableApp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>eddie</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/30591404/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>eddie-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/32301501/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Error that gets generated:

Here is the error that gets generated:

```
$ mvn clean package
Apache Maven 3.8.3 (ff8e977a158738155dc465c6a97ffaf31982d739)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.8.3
Java version: 1.8.0_292, vendor: Red Hat, Inc., runtime: C:\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.292-2.b10.dev.redhat.windows.x86_64\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------< com.eddie.app:app-wrapper >-----------------
[INFO] Building app-wrapper 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/3.2.0/maven-dependency-plugin-3.2.0.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/3.2.0/maven-dependency-plugin-3.2.0.pom (18 kB at 35 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/34/maven-plugins-34.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/34/maven-plugins-34.pom (11 kB at 114 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/3.2.0/maven-dependency-plugin-3.2.0.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/3.2.0/maven-dependency-plugin-3.2.0.jar (205 kB at 888 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from eddie: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/22513588/packages/maven/com/ivans/connect/Connect/8.6.4g-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading from eddie-snapshots: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/32301501/packages/maven/com/ivans/connect/Connect/8.6.4g-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded from eddie-snapshots: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/32301501/packages/maven/com/ivans/connect/Connect/8.6.4g-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (954 B at 1.5 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading from eddie-snapshots: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/32301501/packages/maven/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading from eddie: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/22513588/packages/maven/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml (2.1 kB at 7.2 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from eddie: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/22513588/packages/maven/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading from eddie-snapshots: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/32301501/packages/maven/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/maven-metadata.xml (1.6 kB at 20 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from eddie: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/22513588/packages/maven/org/apache/commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient/3.1.0/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient-3.1.0.pom
[INFO] Downloading from eddie-snapshots: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/32301501/packages/maven/org/apache/commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient/3.1.0/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient-3.1.0.pom
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient/3.1.0/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient-3.1.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient:jar:3.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The artifact javax.xml:jaxrpc:jar:1.1 has been relocated to javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1
[INFO] Downloading from eddie: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/22513588/packages/maven/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar
[INFO] Downloading from eddie-snapshots: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/32301501/packages/maven/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.727 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-01-13T09:48:53-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project com.eddie.app:app-wrapper Could not resolve dependencies for project com.eddie.app:app-wrapper:jar:1.0.0: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE in eddie (https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/22513588/packages/maven) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project test-dl-carrier: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ivans.download:test-dl-carrier:jar:1.1.3: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE in eddie (https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/22513588/packages/maven)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:269)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
```

Comment: The first question which comes to my mind: `and wrap it in a new jar` why? What is the purpose?

Comment: I'm using this pom as a template. The template will always require the 'myAwesomeReusableApp' jar, but some projects may need additional dependencies to go into this new jar and some just need this 1 jar.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer. If you like to have a dependency define it simply. No need to repackage ??? Why would you like to repacke?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you don't understand. I thought Maven was a tool that could collect your dependencies and build whatever artifact you want (war file, jar file, etc.). In my case, it is finding the dependency, but then it appears to be rebuilding the dependency. I just want the maven equivalent of going to the maven repo and downloading the jar file. I don't care about that jar's pom file or what it consists of (and neither do the users). It sounds like what you are asking me to figure out how that jar file in the maven repo got built and then add that build process to my current build?

Comment: The exact error I'm getting is: 

`Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:jar:1.2.1`

Why is it looking for spring-boot-starter...it is not in my pom.xml as you can see above.

Comment: ` I don't care about that jar's pom file or what it consists of (and neither do the users). `. Using Maven is to have a defined set of dependencies in your pom file defined. Also building your own jar/war etc. Furthermore ignoring the artifacts pom file means you ignore all their dependencies. If it is not in your pom file that means it's a transitive dependency wich is needed to build that jar because it's used in that code. Also seeing that this dependency is quite old... If this is a kind of creating an executable jar this is the wrong way. In particular with spring boot..

Comment: ' Using Maven is to have a defined set of dependencies in your pom file defined.' There is 1 dependency in the pom. When you use a public artifact, like one from apache, do you check to see what dependencies it has? No, instead you just reference the version that you want to use in your pom. What I'm doing is very similar to that. I created an app that is in jar format. I want other users to be able to use my app in their java projects.

Comment: Using an app or use your library which has dependencies of it's own...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the pom file to a build.gradle file and was successfully able to create a wrapper jar file.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = uri('https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/22516918/packages/maven')
        name "GitLab"
        credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
            if (System.getenv('CI_JOB_TOKEN')) {
                name = "Job-Token"
                value = System.getenv('CI_JOB_TOKEN')
              } else {
                 name = 'Private-Token'
                 value = gitLabPrivateToken
              }
        }
        authentication {
            header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
        }
    }

    maven {
        url = uri('https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/32306969/packages/maven')
        name "GitLab-snapshots"
        credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
            if (System.getenv('CI_JOB_TOKEN')) {
                name = "Job-Token"
                value = System.getenv('CI_JOB_TOKEN')
              } else {
                 name = 'Private-Token'
                 value = gitLabPrivateToken
              }
        }
        authentication {
            header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.eddie.myApp:myAwesomeReusableApp:1.0.0'
}

jar {
    from(configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
                'Built-Date': new Date(),
                'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version'),
                'Main-Class': 'com.eddie.myApp.Processor'
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
                if (System.getenv('CI_JOB_TOKEN')) {
                name = "Job-Token"
                value = System.getenv('CI_JOB_TOKEN')
              } else {
                 name = 'Private-Token'
                 value = gitLabPrivateToken
              }
            }
            if(project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')) {
                url "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/32306969/packages/maven"
            } else {
                url "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/22516969/packages/maven"
            }
            authentication {
                header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

There is probably a solution with maven, but I discovered that Gradle was easier to implement for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exclusions on the dependency to avoid the download of the transitive dependencies.

But usually, these transitive dependencies are needed to run your JAR, so you should be really be sure you don't need them.